# Reference the bibliography as a whole

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I am using biblatex for my bibliography, and it's working fine:

```
\printbibliography[title={Sources}]
```

Everything works as expected. What I'd like to do, though, is something like

```
See sources on page~\pageref{bibliography).
```

I have tried to add `\label{bibliography}` above `\printbibliography` but it's always off by one page: How can I correctly reference the first page of my bibliography?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another trick is

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\label{bibliography}}
```

Comment: Ah, I'm sure that'll be useful at some point... Thanks, I'll make this the official answer.

Comment: When you have more than one `\printbibliography`, this labels each of them.  Instead, in this case I use `\printbibheading[title={\label{bib}Source}]` (thanks to the other answer).

Answer (score 7):

In a desperate attempt I tried

```
\printbibliography[title={\label{bibliography}Sources}]
```

and it seems to be working as expected!