# How can I refer to the bibliography chapter generated by biblatex using cleveref?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using biblatex to generate my bibliography using `printbibliography`.

I want to reference the bibliography from another chapter, using cleveref like this:

```
\Cref{chap:bibliography} lists the referenced material in IEEE format.
```

I tried using the answers from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147187/reference-the-bibliography-as-a-whole):

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\label{chap:bibliography}}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

But all I got was an undefined reference and questions mark in place of the reference

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  It is better to provide complete compilable documents rather than code snippets, see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so we know which documentclass and packages you are using.

Answer (score 4):

So this does not technically answer my question, as this answer does not use cleveref, but for me it produces identical results to cleveref.

My first mistake was that I placed `\AtBeginBibliography` above `printbibliography` when it should have been in the document preamble.

I still couldn't get cleveref to work, but I managed to get similar results using hyperref:

```
\hyperref[chap:bibliography]{Bibliography} lists the referenced material in IEEE format.
```

Comment: It's not clear whether your solution required an `\AtBeginBibliography` statement or not.